# I can't load kext on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos-sierra, kernel-extension

I'm trying load kext on macOS Sierra. but error occur.
Please, someone help me.

1.

## csrutil disable && reboot

disable SIP.

2.

## nvram boot-"debug=0x146 kext-dev-mode=1" && reboot

kext developer mode.

3.
kext build with xcode.

4.

## cp -rf /Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData//Build/Products/Debug /System/Library/Extensions

5.

## kextload /System/Library/Extensions/test.kext

/System/Library/Extensions/test.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) validation failure (plist/executable); check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).

6.

## kextutil /System/Library/Extensions/test.kext

...
Code Signing Failure: code signature is invalid

Comment: When booted into your test system, what does `csrutil status` output? And are you sure your kext does not show up in `kextstat`?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. Any solution right now?

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting out with kext dev, don't put your kext in the Library/Extensions folder since this may cause a disaster if something goes wrong in your kext and prevent your OS from booting. You can load it from anywhere other than Library/Extensions.

The kext should load unless there's an obvious mistake of having csrutils being enabled. Just like someone from the comments said, check whether you have SIP turned on by using `csrutil status`. If not, I'm guessing you have a faulty plist in your project. Please post your plist so that I can take a look.

Referring to your 2. Starting from sierra `nvram` will not work unless you're in recovery mode.

If you have your csrutil disabled, you'll see

`kext signature failure override allowing invalid signature -67050 0xFFFFFFFFFFFEFA16 for kext`

after your Code signing failure prompt and then load your kext successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding step #2, [according to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/KernelExtensions/KernelExtensions.html),

> As of macOS El Capitan, the kext-dev-mode boot-arg is now obsolete.
>
> ```
> $ sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1" # Has No Effect
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add Oracle editor in this authorization list.
Restart your mac in Recovery mode (cmd + R)

Then open a Terminal and enter :

`spctl kext-consent add VB5E2TV963`

Restart your mac. 
Ok for me with Mojave and Virtual Box 6.